# Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed

Tags: python, zip

I am trying to unzip a file and extract all to the target directory. But it is giving me an error. Trying this small piece of code for a few days. Running into multiple errors. This code was working in the morning and now it is giving me this error.

Code:

```
def main():
file_name = 'D:\\BR_Files\\DDD_XXX_08042019_D.zip'
target_dir = 'D:\\BR_Files'
pswd = '123456'
pwd = bytes(pswd, 'utf-8')

with pyzipper.AESZipFile(file_name) as parent_file:
    f.pwd = pwd

list_files = parent_file.namelist()

parent_file.extractall(target_dir)

child_file = list_files[0]
print(child_file)

with pyzipper.AESZipFile(target_dir+'\\'+child_file[0]) as newfile:
# extracting the zip
    print(True)
newfile.extractall(target_dir)

parent_file.close()
newfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Complete trace back:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-302-b9e455d215cb> in <module>
     26     newfile.close()
     27 
---> 28 if __name__ == '__main__': main()

<ipython-input-302-b9e455d215cb> in main()
     13     list_files = parent_file.namelist()
     14 
---> 15     parent_file.extractall(target_dir)
     16 
     17     child_file = list_files[0]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzipper\zipfile.py in extractall(self, path, members, pwd)    2093     2094         for zipinfo in members:
-> 2095             self._extract_member(zipinfo, path, pwd)    2096     2097     @classmethod

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzipper\zipfile.py in
_extract_member(self, member, targetpath, pwd)    2146             return targetpath    2147 
-> 2148         with self.open(member, pwd=pwd) as source, \    2149                 open(targetpath, "wb") as target:    2150             shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyzipper\zipfile.py in open(self, name, mode, pwd, force_zip64)    1975         if not self.fp:    1976        raise ValueError(
-> 1977                 "Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed")    1978     1979         if not pwd:

ValueError: Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed
```

Should be able to unzip a file to a target directory.

Comment: Could be a `pyzipper` bug. Suggest you read the code _preceding_ the lines shown in your question and see if you can determine when or why `self.fp` would ever be zero (or other value that would be considered `False` in Python). If you can't, then contact the module's [Maintainer](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipper/).

Comment: That is not a full traceback. Provide both the full traceback and the code that causes it.

Comment: @Dan, Code provided with full traceback. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are accessing `parent_file` after the `with` statement has finished.

You need to indent your code so that all accesses to a name bound by the `as` clause of the `with` statement are within the `with` statement.

That is to say that your code should look more like this:

```
def main():

    file_name = 'D:\\BR_Files\\DDD_XXX_08042019_D.zip'
    target_dir = 'D:\\BR_Files'
    pswd = '123456'
    pwd = bytes(pswd, 'utf-8')


    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(file_name) as parent_file:
        f.pwd = pwd

        list_files = parent_file.namelist()

        parent_file.extractall(target_dir)

        child_file = list_files[0]
        print(child_file)

    with pyzipper.AESZipFile(target_dir+'\\'+child_file[0]) as newfile:
        # extracting the zip
        print(True)
        newfile.extractall(target_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Note that I have not tested this code.

Also no need to close the `parent_file` or `newfile` as the `with` statement does that automatically.

Comment: Dear @Dan, it worked. my bad, I was trying to put the code in the method main and missed the indent. Learning with every mistake and Stack overflow is guiding me through. Thank you so much.